# CARET xgbtree warning: `ntree_limit` is deprecated, use `iteration_range` instead

Tags: r, warnings, knitr, xgboost, r-caret

```
cv <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = prSummary,
  seeds = set.seed(123))

turn_grid_xgb <- expand.grid(
  eta = c(0.1,0.3,0.5),
  max_depth = 5,
  min_child_weight = 1,
  subsample = 0.8,
  colsample_bytree = 0.8,
  nrounds = (1:10)*200,
  gamma = 0)

set.seed(123)
suppressWarnings({
  xgb_1 <- train(label~., data = baked_train, 
             method = "xgbTree",
             tuneGrid = turn_grid_xgb,
             trControl = cv,
             verbose = FALSE,
             metric = "F")
```

Hi, when I was trying to run the above code, the following warnings are shown in the R console. Does anyone know how to get rid of it? I have tried `suppressWarnings()` , `warning = FALSE` on the chunk setting, and it is still there.

thx!!

```
WARNING: amalgamation/../src/c_api/c_api.cc:718: `ntree_limit` is deprecated, use `iteration_range` instead.
[02:15:13] WARNING: amalgamation/../src/c_api/c_api.cc:718: `ntree_limit` is deprecated, use `iteration_range` instead.
[02:15:13] WARNING: amalgamation/../src/c_api/c_api.cc:718: `ntree_limit` is deprecated, use `iteration_range` instead.
```

Answer (score 8):

To get rid of xgboost warnings you can set `verbosity = 0` which will be passed on by `caret::train` to the `xgboost` call:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)


cv <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = prSummary,
  seeds = set.seed(123))

turn_grid_xgb <- expand.grid(
  eta = 0.1,
  max_depth = 5,
  min_child_weight = 1,
  subsample = 0.8,
  colsample_bytree = 0.8,
  nrounds = c(1,5)*200,
  gamma = 0)

set.seed(123)

xgb_1 <- train(Class~., data = Sonar, 
               method = "xgbTree",
               tuneGrid = turn_grid_xgb,
               trControl = cv,
               verbose = FALSE,
               metric = "F",
               verbosity = 0)
```

The current warning means xgboost is changing the name of an argument, but caret is still supplying the old name. Currently it works but with new xgboost versions the argument will be completely replaced, if carets function code is not updated by then the warning will be replaced by an error.

Comment: Is the warning message perhaps something that needs to be addressed? Or can it simply be ignored?

Comment: the current warning means xgboost is changing the name of an argument, but caret is still supplying the old name. Currently it works but with new xgboost versions the argument will be completely replaced, if carets function code is not updated by then the warning will be replaced by an error.

Comment: Thanks @missuse - I recognized the reason for the warning but just wanted to suppress it for now - this was very helpful!

Comment: But I didn't use ntree_limit argument, how come the message reminds me that?

Comment: Caret probably uses it internally with this method